# Adding features from one raster to another using QGIS

Tags: raster, qgis-3, mosaic, cost-path

I use QGIS 3.16 and dont handle Phython.

Eventually I need to do a least cost path analyses (plug in) for migrating animal in a landscape.

For the input cost layer I created a specific raster layer with complex landscape data via the raster calculator. Now I want to add 5 additional cost values from 5 other layers.

(For better understanding: for migrating animals highways, waterways etc. are a high cost factor and need to be added to my original layer which I will use for the least cost path analysis.)
I tried to use the "merge" option, but the outputlayer just looks exactly the same than the one without the added extra cost value features.

Which tool is the right one?

In ArcGIS Desktop I would use "Mosaic".

Comment: Have you tried Build virtual raster?

Comment: You might look at the mosaicking tool in SAGA accessible in the QGIS Processing tools.

Comment: Merge algorithm has layers order, but I never understood how to order them in QGIS and always perform merges with GDAL at the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Johns, I tried the SAGA tool "mosaic" and it did show different values in the new raster (higher cost values), so i guess it worked.
I did not try the other suggestions, they might be valid answers as well-thanks everyone!